# How to meter timer for a concurent kind of job triggered using http endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, micrometer

So we have the app where the http endpoint triggers an async job to completion. The start of the job creates a job id and all the methods and stuff use this for correlation.
We are trying to use the timer for timing the http downloads to third party in the job run sequence. So in our method we create a new timer using registry and give it the job id as the tag. Rest of the stuff is same as mentioned in the docs, we use the wrap over the callable and do our work. The data is exported to new relic.

Once the job finishes the data is visible in new relic and prometheus and its right. But I found that after some time the timer values get reset to zero. SO the percentile values like 95% and avg and 99% all become zero in both prometheus and new relic. What i realized that micrometer clears off the values as it expects the meters to be more global to the app and each http request or job run to update the same meters. But in our case its not like that. We want to do stats over a single job run, so that we can see the stats and events in new relic and all.

Is it not possible in micrometer or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: `We are trying to sue the timer`  **sue** the timer??!

Comment: corrected the mistake.

Comment: My question was more around capability of the framework.

It seems micrometer doesn't offer a way to unregister the metrics once registered, so the metric data continuously flows to the exporter and its values get set to zero in case of the timers. So the timers are long lived meters actually and not something that can be created to track and consume times in a batch and then export and forget it.

The whole point was that i export the job stats to an aggregator like prometheus or new relic and view them anytime later one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a distributed tracing system like [Zipkin](https://zipkin.io/), not a metrics collection system. Zipkin, etc. are optimized around understanding latency contributions of subsystems within a *particular request*.

See more [here](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/16/micrometer-spring-boot-2-s-new-application-metrics-collector#the-distinction-between-metrics-and-tracing) on the distinction between metrics and tracing.

Note that the [Prometheus spec](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_clientlibs/#summary) itself requires decaying quantile values.